# how to drag two view simultaneously

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I just want to know how to drag two views at the same time

1. first view is its original image view
2. Second one is its shadow

I am using `dragShadow` builder to build a drag shadow but when I drag a view using `touchlistner` it is only drag shadow of my main view and the main view is stick on their position ..

so my question is Is there any solution to enable drag both view simultaneously?
thank you for any kind of suggestion..

attach a picture

[image: here is picture]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both ImageView and shadow in ViewGroup, for example, FrameLayout, and drag FrameLayout instead of ImageView.

Comment: very thank you P. Sukharev sir for replying me can u provide some example code that i can clearly understand..